# Getting CustomMessageMissingMethodException when configuring gradle-pitest-plugin

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, pitest

I'm trying to include mutation testing for my Android local UnitTests.
I found https://pitest.org/ framework which I tried to include using the "officially" recommended gradle plugin from here: https://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/

Gradle Wrapper version: 6.5.1

But I can't figure out how to get it up and running. The docs on the plugins webpage are very fragmented and so I don't know if my gradle configuration is even correct.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My `build.gradle (app)` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'info.solidsoft.pitest'

android { ... }

dependencies { ... }

pitest {
    targetClasses = ['training.your.app.data.viewmodel.*']  
    pitestVersion = '1.5.1'
    threads = 4
    outputFormats = ['XML', 'HTML']
    timestampedReports = false
}
```

With this approach the IDE (AndroidStudio 4) gradle sync tells me:

`Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method pitest() for arguments [build_w05scwyltsg8pepn5z5mp7e1$_run_closure3@651693d3] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

If I try to do it via `gradlew pitest` I get the same result.

My best guess is I'm lacking a lot of gradle knowledge.
Any advise?

Comment: There are issues using the standard java gradle plugin for android projects, but this fork should be compatible -> https://github.com/koral--/gradle-pitest-plugin

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But I'm afraid this doesn't work either. When including with Plugin Portal I get `Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'reporting' for root project 'your.training' of type org.gradle.api.Project.` on sync.
When including via maven central I get: `Could not find pl.droidsonroids.gradle:gradle-pitest-plugin:0.2.4.`

Comment: Seems that `0.2.4` and `0.2.3` are somehow not in the maven central repository (`Could not resolve all artifacts`). But I was able to get a successful gradle sync with `0.2.2`. Nevertheless `0.2.2` runs into an issue (`The value for task ':app:pitestDebug' property 'mainClass' is final and cannot be changed any further.`) which was fixed in `0.2.4`. Quite a dilemma.

Comment: Opened an issue for this problem here: https://github.com/koral--/gradle-pitest-plugin/issues/66
The simple truth: Artifacts for `0.2.4` haven't been uploaded to any repository.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to henry's comment I was able to get pitest running with a fork of the gradle-pitest-plugin (https://github.com/koral--/gradle-pitest-plugin).

Long story short:

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'pl.droidsonroids.gradle:gradle-pitest-plugin:0.2.2'
    }
}
```

`build.gradle (app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'pl.droidsonroids.pitest'

android { ... }

dependencies { ... }

pitest {
    reportDir = 'build/pitest/reports'
    targetClasses = ['training.your.app.data.viewmodel.*']
    threads = 6
    outputFormats = ['HTML']
    timeoutConstInMillis = 20000
    verbose = true
}
```

This won't work with Gradle version `6.5.1`. The author of this plugin claims to have this issue fixed with the plugin version `0.2.4`. But this version hasn't been published to maven central yet.

So use Gradle `6.3` with `pl.droidsonroids.gradle:gradle-pitest-plugin:0.2.2` and you're good to go.